# How to create different date ranges based on criteria?

Tags: excel, range, criteria

I have a table with two active columns. In Column A I have all the dates between, let`s say, January 1, 2012 to December 31, 2019. In column B I have a corresponding name. For instance:

[[image]
etc.

I want to create ranges based on criteria, like:

[image]

The trick is, this should be done by calendar year, which means that during the 8-year period, I should have 8 set of 3 columns (from / to / name), one for each calendar year. If one range covers two years (let's say, November 1, 2012 to February 1st, 2013), the last row of 2012 should read
2012-11-01 to  2012-12-31
while the first row of 2013 will read
2013-01-01 to  2013-02-01

I managed to separate the ranges, but for some reason I am not able to go further and do that for each calendar year. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: please show how you `managed to separate the ranges`

Comment: It's a complicated process, but I used a series of helper columns. First, I created a column for each criteria. Using a formula (that basically says something like IF(AND(B2=B1,B2=B3),"",IF(VLOOKUP(A2,$A$1:$A$2200,2,0)=criteria,a2,"")) I obtained the first and last date of each range. Second, I use the SMALL function to write in one column the start date and in the other one the end date. My ranges are separated for the entire period of 8 years, but I don't know how to do that per calendar year.

Comment: So you already have the first step done and the point is to work on the second image, right?

Comment: OK, I managed to come up with something, like breaking the original table (columns A and B) into smaller ones, one per calendar year. That allowed me to obtain the result I wanted. However, Evil Blue Monkey`s solution is more suitable as it allows me to create a smaller file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you want to place your 8 set of 3 columns starting from column G and that your list in the range D:F has headers in row 1 and data from row 2 on. In cell G1 write down your first year (2012), in cell H1 "From", in cell I1 "To" and in cell J1 "Name".

Now in cell H2 write this formula:

```
=IF(IF(OR(IF(AND($E2>=DATE(G$1,1,1),$D2<=DATE(G$1,12,31)),1,0),IF(AND($D2>=DATE(G$1,1,1),$E2<=DATE(G$1,12,31)),1,0)),1,0),MAX($D2,DATE(G$1,1,1)),"")
```

In cell I2 write this formula:

```
=IF(IF(OR(IF(AND($E2>=DATE(G$1,1,1),$D2<=DATE(G$1,12,31)),1,0),IF(AND($D2>=DATE(G$1,1,1),$E2<=DATE(G$1,12,31)),1,0)),1,0),MIN($E2,DATE(G$1,12,31)),"")
```

In cell J2 write this formula:

```
=IF(AND(H2<>"",I2<>""),F2,"")
```

Drag the 3 of them all the way down accordingly to your need. You can then copy the G:J range and paste any time you need next to itself; just change the year in the top left cell and it should do the trick.

Report any question you have or bug you have encountered. If, according to your judgment, this answer (or any other) is the best solution to your problem you have the privilege to accept it ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)).

Comment: For some reason, the first two lines are not displaying the right results. I have 2011-12-31 in D2, 2012-12-04 in E2, 2012-02-05 in D3 and 2012-07-06 in E3. Now, H2 is correctly showing 2012-01-01, I2 is showing 2012-12-31, H3 is 2012-01-01 and I3 is 2012-07-06. Now, if I change 2012 for 2013, the first line displays the entire year, second line - some random dates, then a few blank lines followed by the right calculation for the year of 2013. I will also try to look into it and see what's wrong.

Comment: I've tried to copy the formulas from my answer, translate them back, and re-run them. They works for me. How may i help you? Shall i break them into pieces?

Comment: OK, it works on Excel 2013. However, it doesn`t work on Excel 365. Strange... Thanks a lot!